# htaccess rewrite /subdirectory to /#/subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

it`s a simple question, I'm working with Navigo for url handling and I need to redirect with 2 rules:

1. Every http:// should be https:// (I have this solved)

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
   ```
2. Also I need to every subdirectory as "/sample" to be "/#/sample"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/#]+) /#/$1 [NC, NE, R=301, L]
```

Rewrite Base should be `/` but maybe you have something else, depending on your setup.

Test it in a fresh browser in incognito mode.

Comment: Hi @wp78de, how it will be the final version of code with the 2 rules? Remember: 
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: @PabloFerder simply combine it.